# File Upload MVC.NET HttpPost

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, multipartform-data

I'm having following code

```
[HttpPost]
public void InsertEmployee(Employee emp)
{
    ...
    ctx.Employees.Add(emp);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

I'm trying to upload a photo (byte[]) from javascript

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file", files[0]);
formdata.append("Name", $('#Name').val());
formdata.append("DateOfBirth",$('#dateOfBirth').val());
formdata.append("cityid",$('#cmbCities').val());

$.ajax({
    processData: false, 
    contentType: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "/test/InsertEmployee",
    data: formdata,
    dataType: 'json'
})
.done(function () {
    dialog.dialog("close");
    $('#example').DataTable().ajax.reload();
});
```

This method returns error from c#: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Form is inside popup, and I'm using

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: What line is throwing an exception?

Comment: take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949064/getting-base64-error-when-uploading-an-image-asp-net-mvc

Comment: Sakir, thank you. I was expecting byte[] instead of HttpPostedFileBase.

Comment: Hope it solved you problem